# what could be the solution for the bench that does not find port when starting?

Tags: workbench, ubuntu-22.04, erpnext, frappe, frappe-charts

Port 8000 is being used by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server on a different port.
As that error occurs after running the bench start command, I tried to stop other apps that are using that port, but I failed. I also tried to change the port number so that it could use that, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port using `bench`. It should take care of the problem. Also redis ports.

```
bench set-nginx-port 8080
```

Just type `bench` and enter and go through the many commands and options that can be done through bench. Attach `--help` to the command to see the usage.

If you've done that, then you need to rephrase your question so it would reflect what have you done exactly trying to solve the problem.